# Squid Proxy StoreID use with pfSense

Tags: cache, squid, pfsense

Hello fellow StackExchange users,

I am wondering if anyone can help me with learning more about Squid's StoreID?

I have been researching this for some time. I got the web cache accelerator to work however at times I feel it is lacking with the security of itself and or it could cache more.

It does work.

[photo of hits in web cache/accelerator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR0aM.png)

Here is my config I am using SSL certificates on some devices and some do not have them and work in transparent mode:

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 192.168.1.1/32
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

acl splice_only src 192.168.1.8 #Tasha iPhone
acl splice_only src 192.168.1.10 #Jon iPhone
acl splice_only src 192.168.1.11 #Amazon Fire
acl splice_only src 192.168.1.15 #Tasha HP
acl splice_only src 192.168.1.16 #iPad

acl NoSSLIntercept ssl::server_name_regex -i "/usr/local/pkg/url.nobump"

acl markBumped annotate_client bumped=true
acl bump_only src 192.168.1.3 #webtv
acl bump_only src 192.168.1.4 #toshiba
acl bump_only src 192.168.1.5 #imac
acl bump_only src 192.168.1.9 #macbook
acl bump_only src 192.168.1.13 #dell

ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump splice splice_only
ssl_bump splice NoSSLIntercept
ssl_bump bump bump_only markBumped
ssl_bump stare all

acl markedBumped note bumped true
url_rewrite_access deny markedBumped
http_access deny all

#acl SSLIntercept ssl::server_name_regex -i "/usr/local/pkg/url.bump"
#ssl_bump bump SSLIntercept
```

Here is a copy of my personal do not bump file, URLS that are just passed without using the cache and are just spliced without bumping.

```
#Sites to be splice
^.*conviva\.com.*
license\.adrise\.tv.*
c2r\.ts\.cdn\.office\.net
^.*cdn\.office\.net
^.*bitdefender\.net
config\.teams\.microsoft\.com
^.*.azure-devices\.net
substrate\.office\.com.*
hulu\.playback\.edge\.bamgrid\.com
assetshuluimcom-a\.akamaihd\.net
hulu\.sc\.omtrdc\.net
infinity-c33\.youboranqs01\.com
beacons\.extremereach\.io
^.*tubi\.video
^.*tubi\.io
a-fds\.youborafds01\.com
youboranqs01\.com
amzpvxrayasset-a\.akamaihd\.net
pv-cdn.net
^.*media-amazon\.com
aiv-delivery\.net
unagi\.amazon\.com
atv-ps\.amazon\.com
pv-cdn\.net
fls-na\.amazon\.com
^.*aiv-cdn\.net
c0a299900000\.local
update\.microsoft\.com
update\.microsoft\.com\.akadns\.net
delivery\.mp\.microsoft\.com
appldnld\.apple\.com
configuration\.apple\.com
gdmf\.apple\.com
mesu\.apple\.com
oscdn\.apple\.com
osrecovery\.apple\.com
skl\.apple\.com
swcdn\.apple\.com
swdist\.apple\.com
swscan\.apple\.com
updates-http\.cdn-apple\.com
updates\.cdn-apple\.com
appldnld\.apple\.com\.edgesuite\.net
entrust\.net
digicert\.com
apple-cloudkit\.com
apple-livephotoskit\.com
gc\.apple\.com
icloud-content\.com
apple\.com
cdn-apple\.com
icloud\.com
api\.apple-cloudkit\.com
^.*appattest\.apple\.com
^.*itunes\.apple\.com
^.*mzstatic\.com
itunes\.com
music\.apple\.com
app-site-association\.cdn-apple\.com
app-site-association\.networking\.apple\.com
xp\.apple\.com
play\.google\.com
android\.com
^((alt[0-9]-mtalk\.)|(mtalk\.)|(mtalk-(staging|dev)\.))google\.com
google-analytics\.com
googleusercontent\.com
^((gvt)([0-9]))\.com
ggpht\.com
dl\.google\.com
dl-ssl\.google\.com
android\.clients\.google\.com
^(((clients)[0-9])|accounts)\.google\.(com|us)
connectivitycheck\.android\.com
android\.clients\.google\.com
device-provisioning\.googleapis\.com
omahaproxy\.appspot\.com
payments\.google\.com
googleapis\.com
notifications\.google\.com
^(pki|(crl|ocsp)\.pki)\.google\.com
ogs\.google\.com
googleapis\.com
androidmanagement\.googleapis\.com
mservice\.bankofamerica\.com
privacyportal-bofa\.my\.onetrust\.com
bankofamerica\.com
mcafee\.com
kaspersky\.com
kaspersky-labs\.com
dc1-st\.ksn\.kaspersky-labs\.com
dc1-file\.ksn\.kaspersky-labs\.com
dc1\.ksn\.kaspersky-labs\.com
olui2m\.fs\.ml\.com
ml\.com
^.*zoom\.us
^.*teams\.microsoft\.com
teams\.events\.data\.microsoft\.com
statics\.teams\.cdn\.office\.net
^.*(outlook\.)(office365|office)\.com
edge-chat\.facebook\.com
internet\.speedpay\.com
^.*hulustream\.com
cws-hulu\.conviva\.com
^.*hulu\.com
hulu\.hb\.omtrdc\.net
^.*dssott\.com
prod-ripcut-delivery\.disney-plus\.net
^(disney\.(content|connections))\.edge\.bamgrid\.com
disney\.api\.edge\.bamgrid\.com
disney\.playback\.edge\.bamgrid\.com
disney\.my\.sentry\.io
^.*amazonvideo\.com
unagi-na\.amazon\.com
events\.data\.microsoft\.com
tubi\.io
production-public\.tubi\.io
tubitv\.com
caauthservice\.state\.gov
studentaid\.gov
mohela\.com
www\.whitehouse\.gov
www\.rcsdk8\.org
rcsdk8\.powerschool\.com
www\.weaveinc\.org
^.*cdn\.nintendo\.net
^.*bitdefender\.net
```

Here is my Custom refresh_patterns I am using.

```
acl getmethod method GET
acl rewritedoms dstdomain .facebook.com .akamaihd.net .fbcdn.net .google.com .static.com .apple.com .oracle.com .sun.com .java.com .adobe.com .steamstatic.com .steampowered.com .steamcontent.com .google.com
always_direct allow !getmethod
store_id_access deny connect
store_id_access deny !getmethod
store_id_access allow dstdomain
store_id_program /usr/local/libexec/squid/storeid_file_rewrite /var/squid/storeid/storeid_rewrite.txt
store_id_children 10 startup=5 idle=1 concurrency=0

refresh_pattern ([^.]+\.)?(cs|content[1-9]|hsar|content-origin|client-download).[steampowered|steamcontent].com/.*\.* 43200 100% 43200 reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-store override-expire override-lastmod
refresh_pattern ([^.]+\.)?.akamai.steamstatic.com/.*\.* 43200 100% 43200 reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-store override-expire override-lastmod

refresh_pattern -i ([^.]+\.)?.adobe.com/.*\.(zip|exe) 43200 100% 43200 reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-store override-expire override-lastmod
refresh_pattern -i ([^.]+\.)?.java.com/.*\.(zip|exe) 43200 100% 43200 reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-store override-expire override-lastmod
refresh_pattern -i ([^.]+\.)?.sun.com/.*\.(zip|exe) 43200 100% 43200 reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-store override-expire override-lastmod
refresh_pattern -i ([^.]+\.)?.oracle.com/.*\.(zip|exe|tar.gz) 43200 100% 43200 reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-store override-expire override-lastmod

refresh_pattern -i appldnld\.apple\.com 43200 100% 43200 ignore-reload ignore-no-store override-expire override-lastmod
refresh_pattern -i ([^.]+\.)?apple.com/.*\.(ipa) 43200 100% 43200 ignore-reload ignore-no-store override-expire override-lastmod
 
refresh_pattern -i  ([^.]+\.)?.google.com/.*\.(exe|crx) 10080 80% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-no-cache ignore-reload reload-into-ims ignore-private
refresh_pattern -i ([^.]+\.)?g.static.com/.*\.(exe|crx) 10080 80% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-no-cache ignore-reload reload-into-ims ignore-private

#FACEBOOK
refresh_pattern ^http://*.facebook.com/*  10080 80% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-no-cache ignore-reload reload-into-ims ignore-private

#FACEBOOK IMAGES  
refresh_pattern -i pixel.facebook.com..(jpg|png|gif|ico|css|js)  10080 80% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-no-cache ignore-reload reload-into-ims ignore-private
refresh_pattern -i .akamaihd.net..(jpg|png|gif|ico|css|js)  10080 80% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-no-cache ignore-reload reload-into-ims ignore-private   
refresh_pattern -i ((facebook.com)|(85.131.151.39)).(jpg|png|gif)  10080 80% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-no-cache ignore-reload reload-into-ims ignore-private 
refresh_pattern static.(xx|ak).fbcdn.net.(jpg|gif|png) 10080 80% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-no-cache ignore-reload reload-into-ims ignore-private
refresh_pattern ^https?://profile.ak.fbcdn.net*.(jpg|gif|png)  10080 80% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-no-cache ignore-reload reload-into-ims ignore-private

#FACEBOOK VIDEO
refresh_pattern -i .video.ak.fbcdn.net.*.(mp4|flv|mp3|amf)  10080 80% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-no-cache ignore-reload reload-into-ims ignore-private   
refresh_pattern (audio|video)/(webm|mp4)  10080 80% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-no-cache ignore-reload reload-into-ims ignore-private

refresh_pattern -i squid\.internal  10080   80% 79900 override-lastmod override-expire ignore-reload ignore-no-store ignore-must-revalidate ignore-private ignore-auth

range_offset_limit none
quick_abort_min -1 KB
```

Here is my database text file I am using

```
 # Facebook
^https?:\/\/(fbcdn|scontent).*(akamaihd|fbcdn)\.net\/.*\/v\/.*\/(.*\.mp4)   http://facebook.squid.internal/$3
^https?:\/\/fbcdn\-(static|profile)\-a\.akamaihd\.net\/static\-ak\/rsrc\.php\/((?!.*\.(?:js|css|swf)).*)    http://facebook.squid.internal/static/$2
^https?:\/\/(fbcdn|scontent).*(akamaihd|fbcdn)\.net\/(h|s)(profile|photos).*\/(.*\.(png|gif|jpg))(\?.+)?    http://facebook.squid.internal/$5
^https?:\/\/fbstatic\-a\.akamaihd\.net\/rsrc\.php\/((?!.*\.(?:js|css|swf)).*)   http://facebook.squid.internal/static/$1
^http:\/\/.*[steampowered|steamcontent]\.com\/([^?]*)   http://steamupdates.squid.internal/$1
^https?\:\/\/download\.oracle\.com\/((otn\-pub|otn)\/[\d\w]+\/[\d\w]+\/[\w\d\-]+\/[\w\d\-]+\.(exe|dmg|rpm|msi|tar\.(gz|Z)))\?   http://java.oracle.otn.ngtech.squid.internal/$1
^https?\:\/\/([\d\w\-]+)\.oracle\.com\/(([\d\w]+)\/[\d\w]+\/[\d\w]+\/([\d\w\-]+)\/([\d\w]+\/)?[\d\w\-\.\_]+\.(dmg|msi|exe|tar\.gz|tar\.Z))\?    http://java.oracle.download.ngtech.squid.internal/$2
^http:\/\/[^\.]+\.phobos\.apple\.com\/(.*)  http://appupdates.apple.squid.internal/$1
^http:\/\/[^\.]+\.c\.android\.clients\.google\.com\/(.*)    http://androidupdates.google.squid.internal/$1
```

I am using the pre packaged StoreID program found in the Squid Package here is a copy of that code. It is located in the path /usr/local/libexec/squid/storeid_file_rewrite

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Pod::Usage;

=pod

=head1 NAME

 storeid_file_rewrite - File based Store-ID helper for Squid

=head1 SYNOPSIS

 storeid_file_rewrite filepath

=head1 DESCRIPTION

This program acts as a store_id helper program, rewriting URLs passed
by Squid into storage-ids that can be used to achieve better caching
for websites that use different URLs for the same content.

It takes a text file with two tab separated columns.
Column 1: Regular expression to match against the URL
Column 2: Rewrite rule to generate a Store-ID
Eg:
^http:\/\/[^\.]+\.dl\.sourceforge\.net\/(.*)    http://dl.sourceforge.net.squid.internal/$1

Rewrite rules are matched in the same order as they appear in the rules file.
So for best performance, sort it in order of frequency of occurrence.

This program will automatically detect the existence of a concurrency channel-ID and adjust appropriately.
It may be used with any value 0 or above for the store_id_children concurrency= parameter.

=head1 OPTIONS

The only command line parameter this helper takes is the regex rules file name.

=head1 AUTHOR

This program and documentation was written by I<Alan Mizrahi <alan@mizrahi.com.ve>>

Based on prior work by I<Eliezer Croitoru <eliezer@ngtech.co.il>>

=head1 COPYRIGHT

 * Copyright (C) 1996-2023 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors
 *
 * Squid software is distributed under GPLv2+ license and includes
 * contributions from numerous individuals and organizations.
 * Please see the COPYING and CONTRIBUTORS files for details.

 Copyright (C) 2013 Alan Mizrahi <alan@mizrahi.com.ve>
 Based on code from Eliezer Croitoru <eliezer@ngtech.co.il>

 This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 (at your option) any later version.

 This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 GNU General Public License for more details.

 You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.

=head1 QUESTIONS

Questions on the usage of this program can be sent to the I<Squid Users mailing list <squid-users@lists.squid-cache.org>>

=head1 REPORTING BUGS

Bug reports need to be made in English.
See http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/BugReporting for details of what you need to include with your bug report.

Report bugs or bug fixes using http://bugs.squid-cache.org/

Report serious security bugs to I<Squid Bugs <squid-bugs@lists.squid-cache.org>>

Report ideas for new improvements to the I<Squid Developers mailing list <squid-dev@lists.squid-cache.org>>

=head1 SEE ALSO

squid (8), GPL (7),

The Squid wiki http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/StoreID

The Squid Configuration Manual http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/

=cut

my @rules; # array of [regex, replacement string]

die "Usage: $0 <rewrite-file>\n" unless $#ARGV == 0;

# read config file
open RULES, $ARGV[0] or die "Error opening $ARGV[0]: $!";
while (<RULES>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^\s*#?$/;
    if (/^\s*([^\t]+?)\s*\t+\s*([^\t]+?)\s*$/) {
        push(@rules, [qr/$1/, $2]);
    } else {
        print STDERR "$0: Parse error in $ARGV[0] (line $.)\n";
    }
}
close RULES;

$|=1;
# read urls from squid and do the replacement
URL: while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    last if $_ eq 'quit';

    my $channel = "";
    if (s/^(\d+\s+)//o) {
        $channel = $1;
    }

    foreach my $rule (@rules) {
        if (my @match = /$rule->[0]/) {
            $_ = $rule->[1];

            for (my $i=1; $i<=scalar(@match); $i++) {
                s/\$$i/$match[$i-1]/g;
            }
            print $channel, "OK store-id=$_\n";
            next URL;
        }
    }
    print $channel, "ERR\n";
}
```

Please let me know if anything is wrong with this. I am getting hits a lot of them and it works however I feel like I am lacking in the security of this somewhat. I do not want any Containers/Jails/VMs to be able to break out of the cache and attack my file system. I am using Squid's helper file. Please let me know if I can change anything to make this more secure.

Ref:
https://fazar.net/storeid-support-caching-youtube-dan-facebook-https/
https://github.com/rudiservo/pfsense_storeid
https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/StoreID
http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/StoreID/DB
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ucokkarnadi/tempat-sampah/master/squid.conf
https://github.com/hscbrasil/hsc-dynamic-cache
https://research.facebook.com/blog/2016/4/the-evolution-of-advanced-caching-in-the-facebook-cdn/

Comment: ^https?:\/\/(fbcdn|scontent).*(akamaihd|fbcdn)\.net\/(h|s)(profile|photos).*\/(.*\.(png|gif|jpg))(\?.+)?    http://facebook.squid.internal/$5   what does the $5 do if no variable has been declared, i understand it in a regex use.